# getting error as list index out of range

Tags: python

I have the following program to calculate the percentage of CO2 every year.
I get an error, **"list index out of range"**, once the entire program runs on the following line:

```
m= co2level[i+1][1]
```

Code:

```
# Program to calculate percentage of CO2 every year     

co2level = [(2001,320.93),(2003,322.16),(2004,328.07),
             (2006,323.91),(2008,341.47),(2009,348.22)]
i = 0

while i!=len(co2level):

   m= co2level[i+1][1] # I am getting error here as list index out of range
   n= co2level[i][1]
   percentage=((m-n)/n)*100
   print " Change in percentage of CO2 in year %r is"%co2level[i][0],percentage

   i+=1
```

Comment: Your i+1 index is longer than your list, which thus throws an error. I think what you want is `m=co2level[i][0] and n=co2lvel[i][1]`

Comment: `while i<len(co2level)-1:` if you are going out of your bounds make sure you stay!

Comment: Thanks user1767754 this while loop has sorted my problem.

Comment: Chris, your solution is giving me an output for the year however I want to find the percentage of the CO2 in all years and print  the percentage so the answer of User1767754 helped me out but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the bounds error like this:

```
co2level = [(2001,320.93),(2003,322.16),(2004,328.07),
             (2006,323.91),(2008,341.47),(2009,348.22)]
i = 1

while i != len(co2level):
   old = co2level[i-1][1]
   act = co2level[i][1]

   percentage=((act-old)/old)*100
   print (" Change in percentage of CO2 in year %r is " %co2level[i][0],percentage)

   i+=1
```

You start with the 1st year you can get a "delta" for and inspect the one before this. You compare act to old so you are not going over the bound.

Answer (score 0):

Python is 0 indexed; that means for a list with *n* elements, the first element of a list is at index 0 and the last element is at index *n - 1*

Consider the following snippent from your code:

```
while i!=len(co2level):
   m= co2level[i+1][1]
```

The line `m = co2level[i+1][1]` implies that you start iterating from the element at index 1 `(2003,322.16)` and tries to get the item at index `6` at the end which causes the error. Morover you have an error in how you assigned `m` and `n`. To correct this you can do:

```
i = 0
while i!=len(co2level):
   m= co2level[i][0] # I am getting error here as list index out of range
   n= co2level[i][1]
   percentage=((m-n)/n)*100
   print" Change in percentage of CO2 in year %r is"%co2level[i][0],percentage
   i+=1
```

The more pythonic way (using for loops) will be

```
for i in co2level:
    m = i[0]
    n = i[1]
    percentage=((m-n)/n)*100
    print" Change in percentage of CO2 in year %r is"%co2level[i][0],percentage
```

better still:

```
for i in co2level:
    m, n = i
   percentage=((m-n)/n)*100
   print" Change in percentage of CO2 in year %r is"%co2level[i][0],percentage
```